# Há necessidade de se instalar um plugin php no Aptana 3, como o PDT por exemplo?

Tags: php, aptana, pdt

Passei a utilizar o Aptana Studio como IDE para desenvolver em PHP, em especial pelas facilidades em controlar tarefas, bem como pela integração completa com o Git.

Porém sinto como se ele não estivesse completo para se desenvolver em php, como acontece com o PDT. É possível, ou mesmo necessário, instalar o plugin do PDT no Aptana?

Se for, qual a melhor maneira, uma vez que o PDT foi feito para se usar com o Eclipse? (Ainda que o Aptana tenha o Eclipse como base, mas vi vários posts falando sobre a incompatibilidade com o PDT).

**Obs**.: Utilizo a versão atual, Aptana Studio 3.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há necessidade de se instalar plugin algum no Aptana (também uso esta versão), porem o Aptana possui algumas falhas como não avisar que determinado cabeçalho de um método esta escrito de forma errada (o o método não existe) mas no geral ele reconhece bem a sintaxe, percebi que é novo a utilizar esta IDE então recomendo uma serie de videos onde é demonstrado o uso da IDE para todas as suas utilidades (sincronização com servidor FTP, criação de snippets) [Link para vídeo aulas que ensinam a trabalhar com a IDE](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=aptana%20studio%203%20rbtech)